# Android Studio wont let me upload APK because of missing JAR signature

Tags: android, android-studio, signing, jar-signing

I'm trying to Upload a simple App to the Play store but it won't let me Upload it because I'm apparently missing the JAR signature.

I already looked around for Solutions but none of the tips on other Threads helped me. I checked V1 and V2 Signatures I checked all the passwords and I also tried enabling Signing in the project structure. I also tried a fresh Install of Android Studio on an other PC and creating a new project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQpRS.jpg

Would be amazing if you guys have a Idea how to fix this Issue... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you checked both signatures? V1 & V2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello guys I've been struggling with this for 2 days now and I finally found a solution.
It seems like the Andoird Studio Signer can be buggy. My solution is getting 3rd party Software to sign the App ... I don't want to promote anything here but if you have the same problem just google Android APK signer and you will find what you need.

This has been a very Frustrating Journey because I would not have thought that it was a problem with Android Studio and I hope this helps someone in the Future.